# Inconsistent behaviour when changing console screen buffers on different windows 10 machines

Tags: c, winapi, console-application

So I've been messing around with console screen buffers and I've noticed that my code does not work in the same way when I compile and run it on different machines.
So when I change the buffer using `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer` on my laptop that's running **Windows 10 Home**, I get the expected result of the screen changing. When I output something using `printf`, it will output to the new buffer that I changed to. However, on my desktop running **Windows 10 Enterprise N 2016 LTSB**, when I change the buffer and output something with `printf`, it will instead output to the original buffer and not the newly set active buffer. When I return to the old buffer I see the text that I've output. Now since I don't have my laptop available atm, I've setup a **VM running Windows 10 Pro**, installed VS community and compiled my code and saw the same results that I've got when doing this on my laptop.

My questions are:

- Which one of these two behaviours is correct?
- How would I go about fixing this inconsistency?

The effect that I want is to be able to write to the new buffer with printf after setting it to be the active buffer.

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    HANDLE old_scrbuff = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE new_scrbuff = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    while (TRUE)
    {
        c = _getch();                   //_getch has a bug on April update of windows 10. Use static linkage with an older SDK
        printf("%d %c\n", c, c);
        if (c == 0 || c == 224)
        {
            c = _getch();
            SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(new_scrbuff);
            HANDLE swap = old_scrbuff;
            old_scrbuff = new_scrbuff;
            new_scrbuff = swap;
            printf("%d %c\n", c, c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried different SDK versions, but they don't seem to have an impact on how this code executes.
The project uses Windows SDK Version: 10.0.16299.0
VM Windows version is 10.0.17763 Build 17763
Desktop Windows version is 10.0.14393 Build 14393

Comment: I would add error checking to make sure the functions are actually succeeding. That is what the return values are for... Are you certain that changing the buffer is actually supposed to affect `printf`? This example and explanation make me think it probably doesn't. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-and-writing-blocks-of-characters-and-attributes

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, I've forgot to mention.The functions are succeeding.
Edit: I had suspicions that it shouldn't affect printf, especially since the docs for `SetConsoleActiveBuffer` only mentions changing what's displayed.However this difference in behaviour on different systems was odd to me and I really wasn't sure which one was actually right, it might've been just a side-effect omitted from the docs for some reason. I guess I should use `WriteConsoleOutput` instead. Maybe implementing my own `printf` where I just use `sprintf` to format and pass it to `WriteConsoleOutput` is a good idea?

Comment: Though one small problem would be that I planned this for outputting text from functions loaded from DLLs which I am not writing. I wanted to have them in their own screen buffer and swap between buffers when necessary.